# How can I use versions.sty to change a section header?

Tags: sectioning, versions

I am trying to have different section headers in different versions of a document using versions.sty (0.55). I get and error while compiling; here is a MWE :

```
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
%!TEX TS-program = pdflatexmk 
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{versions}
\includeversion{draft}

\begin{document}
\section{\begin{draft}This is a draft of\end{draft} Introduction}
Some text
\end{document}
```

The error is :

```
Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9 ...This is a draft of\end{draft} Introduction}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect `\section{\protect\begin{draft}This is a draft of\protect\end{draft} Introduction}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Thanks, but that does not work here. (I always try \protect and \expandafter...)

Comment: Compilation worked for me with `\protect` ...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer My wrong, I missed the second \protect. It works with `\includeversion` but I get an error if I  `\excludeversion`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\section{\protect\begin{draft}This is a draft of\protect\end{draft} Introduction}` works for the headline and the ToC, but not for the page header.

The `versions` package also offeres the macro `\processifversion`, which can be used here. It works for all three, head line, ToC, and page header.

**Edit:**

The space between *of* and *Introduction* must be part of the optional content. Otherwise it will appear in the headline, if `\excludeversion` is used. And `\protect` can't be used, because with it, *This is a draft of* will appear in the heading regardless of `\excludeversion`. This doesn't look nice in the source, but the space logicaly belongs to the draft content.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{versions}
\includeversion{draft}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\section{\protect\processifversion{draft}{This is a draft of }Introduction}
% watch the  space -----------------------------------------^
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great. However the `\protect` solution generates an error if I say `\excludeversion{draft}`.

Comment: @A.G. I don't get an error here, but the heading still contains _This is a draft of_. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I get a compile error and entering scrollmode produces the output with *this is a draft of*. The error message is `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\@sect ...@svsec }\interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par }
                                                  \endgroup \csname #1mark\e...
l.10 ... draft of\protect\end{draft} Introduction}`. But your solution works much better anyways.

Comment: @A.G. ah, the error is produced by the version with the `draft` environment.

Comment: @A.G. I changed my answer. It should now work for headline, ToC, and header with both `\includeversion` and `\excludeversion`.